Is the current that flows through the battery connected to a DC-AC inverter the same as at the inverter output?
I have a 12V car battery that I want to use with a 12-220V DC-AC invertor (I will discharge it only to 50% or higher.)
I want to load the inverter with about 500W consumer. As I understand it, to calculate the current I need to divide power 500W not by inverter output 220V voltage, but by the original source voltage - that is, the battery voltage 12V (assuming the invertor has 100% efficiency.)
Current should be about 41A then.
I also want to connect an automatic relay module that will open the circuit (no current will be) if the battery voltage is lower than some specified value to prevent battery deep discharge, and close it back if voltage is higher.
Such modules as I see on circuits schematics are connected to the battery, before the inverter (obviously, since the inverter output voltage is different.)
All the modules I see have current limitation at 10-40 amperes.
Will the 41A current also flow through the battery so that I need to find another module or such will the high flow only in the circuit after the inverter, where there is 220V, so I can safely use it?

100% efficiency is a poor assumption. It will likely be 80%-85%, or 90% at best. This matters cause this loss will contribute several amps to your calculation at this voltage.

@MOSFET, I know, but I used such assumption to not consider it, since it is not the main topic of the question. Everyone focuses on it though(

Everybody focuses on it because it makes a difference when you work with these systems...

Like Mike said, you need to consider the losses when doing power calculations. Unless this is a "theoretical textbook problem", your assumption will yield optimistically unrealistic results (and melted relays). Furthermore, you will have further losses than your "theoretical" approach - the battery voltage will sag under load and need to draw extra current to compensate for the voltage drop. You're going to be closer to 50A than 40A in real life.

@MOSFET, yeah, but I consider it, I just wanted not to focus on it here. However, maybe it will be useful for others

close the circuit usually means that the circuit is in a conductive state ... please use clear terms, such as in conducting state or activate the circuit

You cannot use those modules safely if they can only handle 40A.
The calculated 41A is the current from the battery.  That's 500 watts /12V = 41.7A.
The current on the AC side will be 500W/220V = 2.3A.
There will be losses in the inverter, meaning that you will need even more current from the battery than calculated.
You need to find a battery protection module that can handle much more than 40A.  To be safe, I'd be looking for one that can handle at least 80A.
A quick look around the internet shows that they are available with the needed current rating.

Unfortunately, at least in my region I can't find higher then 50A modules, again, at least as cheap <40A modules. Maybe somehow detect battery voltage on the inverter output side?

Or, how about that (I am rather physicist, then electrical engineer): connect parallelly to the battery some microcontroller, and measure using it voltage, again, parallelly. Cut one wire from battery to inverter, making open circuit, and attach to the end of cutted wire magnetic element. Make hole under the cut area, so cutted part of the wire with magnet will fall a bit, due to gravity. Now, if controller measures voltage higher than specified value it passes current through additional circuit with coil, that will produce magnetic field, that will attract cutted wire and close the circuit

Or I can use cheap 10A module at inverter output circuit, but connecting to it wire from battery, that is connected to it parallelly

No, the current is not the same, but the POWER is - once the losses are accounted for.
If you want 500W delivered air 230V AC that is 2.174A.
But 500W from a 12V DC battery is 41.67A.
So that is baseline without any losses either side. To size the batteries and cables etc the losses need to be included.
Also if you use a car battery and discharge it to 50% then it will fail in very short time.
I would suggest a second battery designed for that type of load - Optima do batteries for winches that are possible and solar batteries are also applicable.

@Stdugnd4ikbd you should be looking at the Amp hour capacity of the battery as well to work out the load and time.

This part I understand, thank You
